# Extend vim file syntax to another filetype not working

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I want to extend the filetype syntax and highlighting of an existing filetype.  The basic structure of my new file syntax is as follows:

```
" Some local (new) syntax that I want to match
syn match   upfOperator "[&|~><!)(*#%@+/=?:;}{,.\^\-\[\]]"
syn match   upfDefines  "\$\S\+"
syn match   upfDefines  "\${\S\+}"
syn match   upfParens   "[)(}{\[\]]"

" load syntax that I want to extend.  This contains it's own highlight commands
runtime syntax/dtcl.vim

" New highlight statements
hi link upfOperator          Statement
hi link upfDefines           Constant
hi link upfParens            Constant
```

The problem is that all the syntax contained in the dtcl.vim file is NOT highlighting.  I am able to open a dctl file and the highlighting works.  However, when I open the other filetype (*.upf) the upf.vim is loaded but NOT the dtcl.vim.

The dctl.vim doesn't have any "if syntax defined" type commands that would cause the file to not load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *dctl.vim* is a proper Vim syntax script, it does clear any existing syntax items (`:syntax clear`), as all syntaxes are supposed to be. Therefore, you have to move your own `upf...` definitions below the `:runtime`.

To properly load the existing syntax, you should use the following command:

```
runtime! syntax/dctl.vim syntax/dctl/*.vim
```

Your `:runtime syntax/dctl.vim` only considers the first occurrence and no syntax extensions.

Other than that, I see no problems with your approach, as long as you only add some new syntax elements which aren't covered yet (if they are, you probably need to use `containedin=...` in yours). You can use the `:syn list` command to check what's actually defined.